# Windows Authentication and Forms Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have an asp.net site, and I need to use both Windows Auth and Anonymous Auth together.

I need Windows auth as I need to get the username of the logged on user, but also the site runs a web-service which must be accessed anonymously.

If I turn on Windows Auth I can get the user and this works fine, but the site calling the web-service returns a 401 error. If I add in Anonymous access too the site using the web-service works fine, but I can no longer get the username of the logged in user.

How can I get the best of both - i.e. get the user name, but not kill my web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following to disable access to specific locations within your directory tree

```
<location path="path.to.web.service">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

while keeping the main site under control of the Windows authentication.

See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx

Comment: Cool - at risk of sounding like a complete noob, what format should the path.to.web.service be in?

Comment: directory/service.asmx or just service.asmx for you probably